# What are the steps I should take to make video difficult to be downloaded?

Tags: javascript, php, html, video, video.js

I'm using Videojs plugin to show my videos, but there are many issues facing me like when I load video Internet Download Manager and other video downloaders grab it and there is an error appends , so I want to know how specifically make my video protected from downloading.

I have read many questions and answers for the same topic but non of them explained how to specifically do this and all answers talk about but a video link in external JavaScript file and I tried many ways to do so but it isn't working.

How to overcome this issue with Videojs video player plugin?

Comment: The only way to make it undownloadable is to not host the video. Any endpoint that allows the user to view the video is a download point. Can't have one without the other.

Comment: @PatrickEvans How can I do that ?

Comment: @CharlotteDunois I'm coding a courses website and I want to protect videos

Comment: talk to a vendor who can provide you with a one-stop solution for hosting than includes DRM - eg Ooyala - or partner with a provider like Vimeo who offer a 'pro' solution ... having done it myself some years back, I'm always going to leave it to professionals when it comes to DRM implementation ;)

Comment: Hollywood couldn't prevent copying of movies, despite spending billions of dollars. You're not going to have much better luck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This question comes up a lot. You need to understand there is no difference from the servers perspective from download to play, or download to store. If you prevent somebody from download, you also prevent them from watching, which is the same as not not putting the video on the internet. You do have the option of using DRM, But its very complicated to use, and would be best if you just contacted a vendor or supplier to do it for you.

Comment: This is true , but what about saving video link in external js file ?

Comment: You can attempt to validate the HTTP referer, or keep changing the URL. but a dedicated user would figure that out in a few seconds.